# Wireless MultiConnection

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, internet

I have 3 open wireless networks in the library and with the same name but different channels.

One of them has internet Connection but the other two don't, and Windows 7 always connects to the one's that have no internet access.

Since they have the same name I can't specify the one I need, so I turn off the wireless adapter from my laptop and turned on again in order to connect.

How can I specify the wireless network that I need?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10

How to change the priority of cable connection

1. Press the Windows Key + X and select Network Connections from the menu.
2. Press the ALT key, click Advanced and then Advanced Settings.
3. Select the network connection and click the arrows to give priority to the network connection.

How to change the priority of a wireless connection? More info if you follow this link:

http://ecross.mvps.org/howto/change-network-connection-priority-in-windows-10.htm

Comment: Well Thanks For You Info

But I already said it`s windows 7 , and my problem with the 3 wifi network witch have the same name ( not for network connections )

I need a way to connect to the wifi networks by channels number, or by wifi mac address if possible ,, or something like that

Thanks again

Comment: UP UP UP UP UP UP uP UP UP uP uP uP UP UP UP

Answer (score 0):

This article briefly explains how to change the priority of network connections in Windows 7 so that they follow a specific connection order.

**Steps to change the network connection priority in Windows 7**

1. Click Start, and in the search field, type View network connections.
2. Press the ALT key, click Advanced Options and then click Advanced
   Settings...
3. Select Local Area Connection and click the green arrows to give
   priority to the desired connection.
4. After organizing the network connections available according to your
   preferences, click OK.
5. The computer will now follow an order of priority when detecting
   available connections.

**Steps to change wireless network connection priority in Windows 7**

The computer can detect more than one wireless network at a time. This article explains how to prioritize the wireless network you want to connect to first.

1. Click Start, and in the search field, type Network and Sharing
   Center.
2. In Network and Sharing Center, click Manage wireless networks.
3. Click the connection to be given priority (e.g. Connection 2 has
   less priority than Connection 1), and then click Move up.
4. The next time it is detecting the networks, the computer will give
   more priority to Connection 2 than to Connection 1.

Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2526067